# Leaflet Tooltip bug when added leaflet-draw

Tags: javascript, leaflet, html, leaflet-draw

Here's a simple demonstration:
The file leaflet.draw-src.js was downloaded here: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/tree/master/dist

If you remove the script tag with the **leaflet.draw-src.js** the tooltip work just fine, but when added the leaflet.draw it gives the error **Cannot read property 'popupPane' of undefined**.

ps: Not using leaflet-draw is not an option

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <!-- got it from here https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/tree/master/dist -->
    <script src="leaflet.draw-src.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #map-canvas {
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = L.map('map-canvas').setView([-18, -52], 4);

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: "Map data &copy; <a href='http://openstreetmap.org'>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href='http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/'>CC-BY-SA</a>.",
            maxZoom: 18
        }).addTo(map);

        var marker = new L.Marker(L.latLng(-18, -52), {
            icon: new L.icon({
                iconUrl:    'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/images/marker-icon.png',
                iconSize:   [32, 32],
                iconAnchor: [16, 32]
            })
        }).addTo(map);

        marker.bindTooltip("derp", {permanent: true});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Leaflet 1.0, you have to use Leaflet.draw [`leaflet-master`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/tree/leaflet-master) branch, as mentioned on the repo [home page](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw):

> Support for Leaflet 1.0 is in development at the leaflet-master branch.

Unfortunately, even with that version, the Tooltip issue is a known bug ([Leaflet/Leaflet#4760](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4760)) that is not resolved yet.

Comment: Two solutions: Add 'leaflet.draw-src.js' only when needed or rename in the leaflet.draw-src.js file from L.Tooltip to L.Draw.Tooltip

Comment: Also wow, the dist folder on the leaflet-branch is 3 years old.